# How do I listen to resolution change from media stream

Tags: javascript, webrtc

When I call getUserMedia() I can get my current video resolution by using onloadedmetadata on the srcObject.

However, when the video is changing its resolution for some reason; in my example the user rotates the camera to portrait, then my the old video resolution becomes obsolete and I would like to get the new one.

This is how my initial fetch of resolution looks like:

```
this._localVideo.onloadedmetadata = (e) => {
    e.srcElement.videoWidth;
    e.srcElement.videoHeight;
};
```

but how do I know if these values are changing?

EDIT: Turns out re-setting srcObject on the video element triggers onloadedmetadata again with updated values.

Comment: why not listen to orientationchange event?

Comment: I am doing that, but how do I get the new resolution from the video?

Comment: you can call this._localVideo.videoWidth after orientationChange. if this._localVideo == <video>